# After I add MaterialCalendarView, Android studio does not show layout preview

Tags: java, android, android-xml

I want to design ConstraintLayout containing MaterialCalendarView
But when I add MaterialCalendarView to XML file, Android studio doesn't show layout preview:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0yNs.png)

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".fragment.SchedulesFragment">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title_fg_schedules"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/gray_black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/schedules" />

    <com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendarView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_title_fg_schedules"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:mcv_calendarMode="week"
        app:mcv_showOtherDates="all"
        app:mcv_selectionColor="@color/gray" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rcv_schedules"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/calendarView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I hope someone can help me. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

I solved using the issue using the `1.6.0` version instead of the last one.

Put this in your `build.gradle` module:

```
dependencies {   
     implementation 'com.github.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.6.0' 
}
```